# React Native Gifted Chat: How to hide keyboard and text input

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I am making a react native application using expo and am using `react-native-gifted-chat` for a chat like feature (https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat). In this feature, I only want certain users to be able to send a message. The users who cant should only be able to view the messages that have been sent.

In order to implement this, I need a way to hide the keyboard/text input for the users who are not authorized to send a message. I was reading through the documentation and am unsure of how to do this. Is there a way to hide the keyboard/text input and only load the messages?

Not sure if this is relevant but my code for the gifted chat is as follows:

```
<GiftedChat
      messages={this.state.messages}
      placeholder="Send your thoughts?"
      onSend={(messages) => this.sendMessage(messages)}
      user={{
        ...user details
      }}
/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass `null` for the prop `renderInputToolbar`:

```
<GiftedChat
    ...
    renderInputToolbar={() => { return null }}
/>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. The keyboard/text input still appears at the bottom of the page.

Comment: My bad. Edited.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so the keyboard has height 0? Right now it disappears, but there is still a 44px gap between the messages and the bottom of the screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `minInputToolbarHeight` attribute to zero:

```xml
<GiftedChat
    ...
    minInputToolbarHeight=0
/>
```